# finding dM/dE , corresponding to available values in matlab

Tags: matlab, sum, figure, derivative

i have a plot of
plot(M,E)

If now i want to plot  dM/dE vs E means    plot (dM /dE , E), THEN

I have tryed this, but it doesn't work

```
   dM=diff(M)/diff(E);

   dE=diff(E);

   dM_dE=dM/dE;

    plot(dM./dE,E)
```

end

Comment: welcome... diff makes a vector one entry shorter than the inputs, so try this: `plot(dM./dE,E(1:end-1))`

Comment: i appreciate your concern MACRO WASSMER, but when i tried to use the above code its showing that  integers can only be combined with integers of same class or scaler doubles.

Comment: moreover its not a problem of difference , i am trying to find out the derivative  ( dM /dE), Then plot the same with  dE, means           plot(dM./dE ,dE)